# Which one is right usage auf dem Bild or im Bild?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, meaning-in-context

The context is slides of powerpoint presentation.

My sentence:

> The teacher can only share important points on the slide.
> Der Lehrer kann nur wichtige Punkte **auf dem Bild** teilen.

Translator:

> Der Lehrer kann nur wichtige Punkte **im Bild** teilen.

Comment: Please do not add additional questions to a posting that already has an answer. Please ask your new Question here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask and then please roll back this question here to the last version.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Okay. I am sorry. I will keep this in mind. Thank you.

Comment: I assume this refers to a PowerPoint slide? Then the translation "Bild" doesn't fit. The common translation is "Folie".

Comment: @Roland yes, I have mentioned in the question, the context is slide of PPT. I noticed many people using the word Bild while explaning from the PPT slides.  Thank you for suggesting me the word Folie.

Comment: Note this translation is ambiguous because you can read it as "share items which can be seen on the picture" but also "share items to the picture". So better translate "Der Lehrer kann nur wichtige Punkte teilen, die auf/in dem Bild sind".

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are correct and mean the same. The difference in the meaning is very subtile and in most cases irrelevant:

- auf dem Bild
  on the surface of the canvas
- in dem Bild = im Bild
  within the borders

Comment: I have added one more example in the question. When we are talking about copying/writing then will the auf and im can be interchangable?

Comment: @NoishaStudieren In this case it makes a difference. _Auf dem Buch_ means on the cover/surface of the book, while _im Buch_ means in the book (on its pages). (Also it should be _alle Bild**er**_)

Comment: Please do not ask additional questions after the original question has been answered. Stackexchange is not a discussion board. It is a board where someone asks **ONE** question and then other people give answers to this **one** question.